# DXA website using wrong static content version

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5, web8-cu1

We are setting up translated versions of our main website which is using DXA 1.5. Our main website uses version `v0.2` for it's static content. The translated website we setup tries to use version `v1.5`. We tried to find any configuration that could trigger this (as the imported configuration from DXA was v1.5) but could not find any. All configuration is also shared between the Publications.

The problem this gives is that all our resources should be defined as `/system/v0.2/assets/*` but are defined as `/system/v1.5/assets/*`.

Do you have any idea where to look for the misconfiguration?

Kr,

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the documentation (http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-9DF49794-3FA2-4FF2-BF46-966DFAE0044C), the version number of the HTML design is kept in the **HTML Design Configuration** Component, from the  `Building Blocks/Settings/Core/Site Manager/` Folder.

If you want to update the version, you will need to Publish the **Publish HTML Design** page, and refresh the Web application cache as [described in the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v5/GUID-32518F0B-D010-4924-9086-38FF1F59005C).

However, the actual version number used in the assets URL is only there for client side/browser caching, requesting a URL like `/system/v0.2/assets/css/main.css` or `/system/v1.5/assets/css/main.css`, or even `/system/v2.18/assets/css/main.css` should results in the same asset unless there is a previous version cached client side (i.e. in your browser), it doesn't matter what version was published since the Web application filters out the `/v?.?/` part of the URL.